# place cursor after bracket }

Tags: cursor

I am a bit new to Vim.

I would like to know how to place my cursor after the bracket `}`
If I use `l` or`$`, it places my cursor on the bracket. When I go into insert mode by typing `i`, I am inserting text just before the bracket `}`.

Comment: just use `a` to *append* instead of `i`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple solutions, The most "usual" one would be, as @Christian_Brabandt said, to use `a` instead of `i`, in order to `a`ppend instead of `i`nsert.

---

Another solution would be to hit `A` (`shift`+`a`) from anywhere in the line, this will switch you to `insert mode`, and place the cursor at the end of the current line.

---

If you feel like twitching your vim, yet another solution is to add the following to your vimrc:

```
set virtualedit=onemore
```

This will allow you to place your cursor one character after the end of the line. for more info, see `:help virtualedit`

Although, **I wouldn't recommentd you to do that**, especially if you're new to vim.

Comment: thanks a lot , I really like the A (shift+a) method, very useful !

Comment: You're welcome! In a similar fashion, you can use `I` (`shift`+`i`) to edit the start of the line